# correct angular ts implementation issue from overly strong type with use of constructor vs gnOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

in angular how would I do a singular version of this? as in allow me to define the shape without initiating any "fake" values, say I had a singular quiz, because if i dont define the shape of the quiz it throws a `Property 'title' does not exist on type 'quiz'.` and coming up with fake place holder values is very hacky and causes more issues and hacky workarounds down the line

```
export class PlayComponent implements OnInit { 
  quizzes: quiz[]=[];

  constructor(public api: ApiService) {   }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getAllQuizzes().subscribe((res: any)=>{            
        this.quizzes=res
      
    });
}   
}
interface quiz {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you saying that instead of the array of quizzes (this.quizzes), you want to have just a single instance?

Comment: @AaronAverett yes well technically question will be the singular instance, as in this.question that will be retrieved from back end, and i render out all its properties but before ngOnInit happens you get the compiler error above

Comment: What object are you getting from your response? Could you just use a pipe to map it to a quiz object?

Comment: @robbieAreBest I don't think that stop the compiler error of property doesn't exist before the ngOnInit, i assume this involves having values to pipe, which wont exist before it crashes no?

Comment: Are you referencing quiz.title in your template? If so, that is likely why you are getting this error. To get around this you could ngIf or async pipe that section. Could you please post your template as well if you need further help?

Comment: yes its referenced in the template, i know where im gettting the error form there its how to fix it, because you cant `*ngIf="quiz.title"` since it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work for you?  The difference here is that I'm using strong types on the results of API calls, as opposed to "any."

```
export class PlayComponent implements OnInit { 
quizzes: Array<quiz>=[];
question: Question;

  constructor(public api: ApiService) {   }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getAllQuizzes().subscribe((res: Array<quiz>)=>{            
        this.quizzes=res
      
    });
    this.api.getQuestion().then((qResult: Question) => {
        this.question = qResult;
    }, 
    (err) => {
        //handle error
    });
  }   
}

interface quiz {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface Question {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```